# Space appears at the bottom of a Cardview when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Recyclerview with a Cardview and inside there is another Recyclerview like Netflix. So I cann scroll vertical and horizontal. Insider the inner recyclerview there are some cardviews with buttons. My Problem is if I scroll down and up again, then there apears some Space inside the Carview.
How does this happen?

[Start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jNX6.jpg)

[After Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMAYT.jpg)

Any suggestion or idea is helpful.

**Note:** Without the Itemdecoration (Page Indikator) it works and no Space appears.

Comment: Post your code!

Comment: Check Your constraints for the objects in the card view, give them a static contraint

Comment: are you changing width and height of recyclerview or cardview? Post your code for more understanding.